# Find the value of $(1+\alpha)(1+\beta)(1+r)(1+s)$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

If $\alpha,\beta,r,s$ are the roots of $x^{4}-x^{3}+x^{2}+x+3=0$, find the value of $(1+\alpha)(1+\beta)(1+r)(1+s)$.

This question appeared on one of the sample papers which I came across.

My first instinct was to graph the function and find its root using it. However, the function showed no real roots.[image: graph]

Please help me with this question. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why "no real roots" is issue?

Comment: The key mentions that the answer is 5 and I don't know how to find imaginary roots of a polynomial of degree 4 or greater.

Comment: **Hint**: Check Vieta's formulas for [Quartic Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html)

Comment: You have :

$$
\begin{align}\prod (1+x_i)\equiv\thinspace \prod y_i=(-1)^4-(-1)^3+(-1)^2+(-1)+3=5\end{align}
$$

where $1≤i≤4$ and $y_i$ are roots of $P(x-1)$ .

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks

Comment: To get the above start with $f(x)=x^{4}-x^{3}+x^{2}+x+3=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-r)(r-s)$, then think about what $f(-1)$ gives in both expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$(1 + \alpha)(1+\beta)(1 + r)(1 + s) = 1 + s + r + \alpha + \beta + \alpha\beta + \alpha r + \alpha s + \beta r + \beta s + rs + \alpha\beta r + \alpha\beta s+ \alpha rs + \beta r s + \alpha\beta r s$$
By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we know that
$$\alpha + \beta + r + s = 1$$
$$\alpha\beta + \alpha r + \alpha s + \beta r + \beta s + rs = 1$$
$$\alpha\beta r + \alpha rs + \alpha \beta s + \beta r s = -1$$
$$\alpha\beta r s = 3$$
Hence, $(1 + \alpha)(1+\beta)(1 + r)(1 + s) = 1 + 1 + 1 -1 + 3 = 5$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha, \beta, r, s$ are roots of $x^{4}-x^{3}+x^{2}+x+3=0$ then $1+\alpha,1+\beta,1+r,1+s$ are roots of $(x-1)^{4}-(x-1)^{3}+(x-1)^{2}+(x-1)+3=0$ and $(1+\alpha)(1+\beta)(1+r)(1+s)$ is the constant term in the polynomial. Now to expand the whole thing will be a headache but fortunately we don't need to do that. The constant term in $(x - 1)^n$ is always $(-1)^{n}$ for any $n$ so in our case the constant term will be $ 1 -(-1) + 1 + (-1) + 3 = 5$.

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake. It should have been $(x -1)$ instead of $(x +1)$. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped